# Getting HTML content using jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I've got a simple application that requires a DIV to be clicked, and in turn it shows another DIV which needs to have its content updated.

There are around 40 items that will need to be clickable and show the correct label for each.

Here is what I need to happen...

1. User clicks a DIV (drag_me)
2. Information box DIV is then shown (flavour_box)
3. the default word 'Ingredients' is swapped out with the content from the "flavour_descrip" div
4. Also update the 'choc_flavour' div with the name of the ingredient (choc_label)

The data comes from a database, so I'm unable to set individual ID's.

I had a similar issue with draggable's, but that was fixed, and I've tried doign somethign similar to no avail.

Here is the clickable DIV (flavour_descrip is set as hidden in the CSS)

```
<li class="drag_me">
    <div>
        <img src="RASPBERRY.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="choc_label">
        Raspberries
    </div>
    <div class="flavour_descrip">
        Our description will appear here for the DB
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is the HTML for the popup box...

```
<div id="flavour_box">
            <p class"flavour_description">Ingredients</p>
            <div class="flavour_add">Add To Mixing Bowl</div>
            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery snippet for the click (i've commented out the code I had started to rejig, but essentially I need to change the draggable.find to something that will work!)

```
 $(".drag_me").click(function () {
     //var htmlString = ui.draggable.find('.choc_label').html();
     //$('.choc2_flavour').text(htmlString);
     // update the description of the item
     //var htmlString = ui.draggable.find('.flavour_descrip').html();
     //$('.flavour_description').text(htmlString);
     // on click of jar make box pop
     $("#flavour_box").toggleClass("visible");
 });
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

## Added extra question

Now I've had my problem resolved, I need to perform one more task.

Inside the div that gets the details passed using "this", I need to be able to pass one more items to a different piece of script.

The DIV 'flavour_add' is clickable and will need to grab the flavour name to use to update some bits on screen and update a URL on the fly.

```
<div id="flavour_box">
            <p class="flavour_name_label">Label</p>
            <p class="flavour_description">Ingredients</p>
            <div class="flavour_add">Add To Mixing Bowl</div>
            </div>
```

This is the jQuery I have, but using "this" doesn't seem to work

```
$(".flavour_add").click(function () {
         // hide the ingredient box
         $("#flavour_box").toggleClass("hidden");
         // show the continue box
         $("#added_box").toggleClass("visible");
         // get the flavour name
         var flavourLabel = $(this).find('.flavour_name_label').text();
         // update flavour URL
         var _href = $("a.to_step_3").attr("href");
         $("a.to_step_3").attr("href", _href + '&flavour=' + flavourLabel);
         //$("a.to_step_3").attr("href", _href + '&flavour=TestFromAdd');
         // update the mixing bowl list with the ingredient
         $('.choc2_flavour').text(flavourLabel);
         
     });
```

Comment: Where is `choc_flavour`? Do you always have to update the `flavour_box` div, regardless of the clicked `li` (not `div`)? And finally, do the `li` always have the same structure?

Comment: Jegadeesh: this is completely nonsense. this does not help a bit to solve his problem

Comment: For your second question It would be better to open a new question, anyway, the problem is the ".flavour_name_label" is not a child of the clicked element ".flavour_add", try using $("#flavour_box > .flavour_name_label") if #flavour_box is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` to get the reference to the clicked element:

```
$(".drag_me").click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).find('.choc_label').text();

     $("#flavour_box > .flavour_descrip").text(txt);
     $("#flavour_box").toggleClass("visible");
 });
```

Besides, there was a "typo" in your html code, replace:

```
<p class"flavour_description">Ingredients</p>
```

By:

```
<p class="flavour_description">Ingredients</p>
```

Comment: This works, but i can't get it to update the description in the flavour box

I've used this:

 $(".drag_me").click(function () {
  var flavourName = $(this).find('.choc_label').text();
  var flavourDesc = $(this).find('.flavour_descrip').text();
 
   
   $("#flavour_box").toggleClass("visible");
   
   $("#flavour_box > .flavour_description").text(flavourDesc);
  });

Comment: @SimonHume, You have a typo in your code, replace "<p class"flavour_description">Ingredients</p>" by "<p class="flavour_description">Ingredients</p>"

Comment: oh whoops! good spot, that'll be why that part wasn't working!

Comment: I have a quick question in addition to this. Now that works OK, I've got to then grab those details again and pass them to another couple of parts via a different click. Using "this" doesn't seem to work on that, I'll pop the code below if you could shed any light on it for me?

Comment: Ok, but maybe It could be better to open a new question, the answer comments aren't a good place to discuss about those details

Comment: Added to my original question now

Comment: Added a new comment related with this "new" issue, basically, I wouldn't use $(this) for that case because #flavour_box is unique (I think so), so $("#flavour_box > .flavour_name_label") should work

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using jQuery.

```
 $(".drag_me").click(function () {
     $('.flavour_description').text($('.flavour_descrip').html());
     // on click of jar make box pop
     $("#flavour_box").toggleClass("visible");
 });
```

I cannot seem to be able to find the divs for step: 4. Also update the 'choc_flavour' div with the name of the ingredient (choc_label)

I will assume that you mean 'flavour_add' in which case the code should look like this:

```
$('.flavour_add').text($('.choc_label').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $flavourBox = $('#flavour_box');
    var $flavourDesc = $flavourBox.children('.flavour_description');
    var $chocFlavour = $flavourBox.children('.choc_flavour');

    $('.drag_me').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $flavourDesc.html($this.children('.flavour_descrip').html());
        $chocFlavour.html($this.children('.choc_label').html());
        $flavourBox.addClass('visible'); //toggleClass will remove the class if it is there
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

get the text by using "this" (the actual clicked element) and then get the child flavour_descrip div

```
 $(".drag_me").click(function () {
     $("#flavour_box").show();
     $('.flavour_description').text($(this).find('.flavour_descrip').text());
 });
```

then show the flavour_box div and set the value of the div with the flavour_description class